# Iphone unregistering nsnotifications on application will terminate why?

Tags: iphone, terminate, nsnotifications

I have always wondered why is it necessary to unregister your nsnotifications in the application will terminate method. I know that nothing that I can notice happens if I don't, so what are the implications of not doing so?. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

-Oscar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't really any. Everything is torn down on termination, including all your registered notification listeners.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want to receive another notification and start processing it after you've already started to shut things down in applicationWillTerminate.